# Сгруппировать массив

Tags: php, массивы

Есть массив такого вида

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [name] => Внуков Сергій Миколайович
        [sum] => 250
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [name] => Внуков Сергій Миколайович
        [sum] => 250
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [name] => Внуков Сергій Миколайович
        [sum] => 489
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [name] => Внуков Сергій Миколайович
        [sum] => 489
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [name] => Внуков Сергій Миколайович
        [sum] => 489
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [name] => Внуков Сергій Миколайович
        [sum] => 250
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [name] => Внуков Сергій Миколайович
        [sum] => 869
    )

[7] => Array
    (
        [name] => Внуков Сергій Миколайович
        [sum] => 489
    )

[8] => Array
    (
        [name] => Внуков Сергій Миколайович
        [sum] => 869
    )

[9] => Array
    (
        [name] => Внуков Сергій Миколайович
        [sum] => 812
    )

[10] => Array
    (
        [name] => Внуков Сергій Миколайович
        [sum] => 812
    )

[11] => Array
    (
        [name] => Внуков Сергій Миколайович
        [sum] => 812
    )

[12] => Array
    (
        [name] => Внуков Сергій Миколайович
        [sum] => 812
    )

[13] => Array
    (
        [name] => Внуков Сергій Миколайович
        [sum] => 1505
    )

[14] => Array
    (
        [name] => Внуков Сергій Миколайович
        [sum] => 1156
    )

[15] => Array
    (
        [name] => Внуков Сергій Миколайович
        [sum] => 1156
    )

[16] => Array
    (
        [name] => Внуков Сергій Миколайович
        [sum] => 1505
    )
```

)

Как его преобразовать к такому виду использую php 5.3

```
Array(
[0] => Array
   (
       [name] => Внуков Сергій Миколайович
       [sum] => 13780 сумма общая   
   )
)
```

Comment: Вы данные в запросе группируйте получая из базы, а не в массиве.

Comment: Нет не из базы из обеднения двух массивов по ключам,  если бы из базы `group by` и нет вопросов

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно циклом пройти по массиву, в первой итерации получить имя и начальную сумму, а во всех последующих - просто суммировать необходимые значения. После выхода из цикла изменить структуру результирующего массива, путём его перезаписи ранее полученными в цикле данными. На примере это выглядит так:

```
$result = array();

foreach ($array as $arr) {
    !empty($result['name']) ?: $result['name'] = $arr['name'];
    $result['sum'] += $arr['sum'];
}

$result = array($result);

echo '<pre>'; print_r($result); echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Спасибо то что нужно